# Extracting Values from Deep Nested Json - What am I doing wrong

Tags: node.js

So I am using this code and it brings back the higher level array and objects, but then I have another object level with the values that I need to get to, but I don't now how to adjust my code.

**This is the nested json**

```
{
    "cashtb": {
        "response": {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": {
                "Id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "Status": "OK",
                "ProviderName": "App 2.0",
                "DateTimeUTC": "/Date(1663920113994)/",
                "Reports": [
                    {
                        "ReportID": "TrialBalance",
                        "ReportName": "Trial Balance",
                        "ReportType": "TrialBalance",
                        "ReportTitles": [
                            "Trial Balance",
                            "Test Company Ltd",
                            "As at 1 August 2022"
                        ],
                        "ReportDate": "23 September 2022",
                        "UpdatedDateUTC": "/Date(1663920113994)/",
                        "Fields": [],
                        "Rows": [
                            {
                                "RowType": "Header",
                                "Cells": [
                                    {
                                        "Value": "Account"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Value": "Debit"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Value": "Credit"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Value": "YTD Debit"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "Value": "YTD Credit"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }]}]}}}}
```

This is the code I use to extract accounts separately, but I need it to iterate through automatically

```
cashtbarray = cashtb.response.body
console.log('Organisation:', cashtbarray)
const cashflow = {
     
section: cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows[1].Title,
account: cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows[1].Rows[0].Cells[0].Value,
debitvalue: cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows[1].Rows[0].Cells[1].Value,
creditvalue: cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows[1].Rows[0].Cells[2].Value,
ytddebitvalue: cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows[1].Rows[0].Cells[3].Value,
ytdcreditvalue: 
cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows[1].Rows[0].Cells[4].Value,
}
```

This is the for..in loop I tried to use,  but it only takes it to the  object then no values

```
let cellstrip = cashtbarray.Reports[0].Rows; 
   for(let i=0, len=cellstrip.length; i<len; i++){
    for (let valuestrip in cellstrip[i]){
      console.log(valuestrip, cellstrip[i][valuestrip]);
    
    }
  }
```

It looks like this when i run it in test

```
RowType Header
Cells [
  { Value: 'Account' },
  { Value: 'Debit' },
  { Value: 'Credit' },
  { Value: 'YTD Debit' },
  { Value: 'YTD Credit' }
]
RowType Section
Title Revenue
Rows [
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
RowType Section
Title Expenses
Rows [
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
RowType Section
Title Assets
Rows [
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
RowType Section
Title Liabilities
Rows [
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
RowType Section
Title Equity
Rows [
  {
    RowType: 'Row',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
RowType Section
Title 
Rows [
  {
    RowType: 'SummaryRow',
    Cells: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you please post actual code instead of images of code ? I would be much easier to help.

Comment: We got the JSON. Next we need your code. And please format your question properly.

Comment: I think I did it properly

Comment: your json doesn't have ```Reports``` or ```Rows```. are you sure this is the right json you want to process? I believe the output of ```console.log('Organisation:', cashtbarray)``` will be right json which needs to be process. if so, then please post the right json.

Comment: The json is really large, so updating it now

Comment: before i post answer, in your code you are trying to get ```Title``` from the object inside ```Rows``` array. But no such property is present in json you updated. so i don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: oh sorry, I'm trying to get the account name and the 4 values associated with each account name

Comment: Bascially it goes Section (Title).  Then each Section has some accounts and then each account has 4 values, debit, credit, ytddebit and ytdcredit

Comment: I'm trying to get all the sections with the accounts and the values associated with each account

Comment: do you want array of ```{
  section: string;
  account: string;
  debitvalue: string;
  creditvalue: string;
  ytddebitvalue: string;
  ytdcreditvalue: string;
}``` ? if not, can you tell in terms of code/data what you want? section or account are the interpretation of data which you understand, not me!

Comment: yes please!  Sorry, I'm so new to this.  I tried for a week to learn it myself, but got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
const cashflowArray = cashtb.response.body.Reports.map(item => ({
    section: item.ReportTitles[0],
    account: item.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value,
    creditvalue: item.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value,
    debitvalue: item.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value,
    ytdcreditvalue: item.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value,
    ytddebitvalue: item.Rows[0].Cells[3].Value
}));
```

check if this meets your requirement. If you are still stuck, comment the issue.

I don't know how to fetch the section value from your json, change it as per your need.

Comment: So I tried the code but it only bought back one, not all 30 of the sets of data.

Comment: {
    "result": true,
    "cashflowArray": [
        {
            "section": "Revenue",
            "account": "Account",
            "creditvalue": "Credit",
            "debitvalue": "Debit",
            "ytdcreditvalue": "YTD Credit",
            "ytddebitvalue": "YTD Debit"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: How do i get it to return all of the accounts, not just the first one

Comment: This is how i'm putting up the response

Comment: res.json({ result: true, cashflowArray})

Comment: so I updated the code to go to the next level to bring back the values

Comment: const cashflowArray = cashtb.response.body.Reports.map(item => ({
    section: item.Rows[1].Title,
    account: item.Rows[1].Rows[1].Cells[0].Value,
    creditvalue: item.Rows[1].Rows[1].Cells[2].Value,
    debitvalue: item.Rows[1].Rows[1].Cells[1].Value,
    ytdcreditvalue: item.Rows[1].Rows[1].Cells[4].Value,
    ytddebitvalue: item.Rows[1].Rows[1].Cells[3].Value
}));
    res.json({ result: true, cashflowArray})

Comment: so added in another Rows[1] but it only returns 1 item not all of them

Comment: what I actully need to see is this:

Comment: account: value (net of debit and credit value) - for all accounts in the report

Comment: The json you posted doesn't have ```Rows``` inside ```Rows```

Comment: It won't let me load up the whole code

Comment: Use a webpage like [this](http://json2ts.com/) to convert your json into interfaces. Then post your interface.